# Access lightning-record-edit-form fields from parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, child-to-parent, parent-to-child

I have a child component with a lightning-record-edit-form that should work as a standalone component and as a child component as part of another flow.

The form takes inputs from users and then, with preventDefault, repopulates additional fields and then calling the submit.

This works properly when running as standalone, however when the parent component does the submit it fails to access the fields of the child component.

Child JS

```
export default class HandoverFromOpportunity extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement) {

@api recordId;
@api context = 'B';

@api
handleSubmit(event){
    console.log('entered handleSubmit');
    if(this.validateInputs()) {
        if(this.context === 'Close Process') { 
            console.log('entered handleSubmit from Close Process');
            const fields = this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').detail.fields; //RETURNS BROWSER ERROR
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            const fields = event.detail.fields;
            console.log('entered handleSubmit Standalone');
        }
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.expendedFields = fields;        
        try {
            this.updateUserInputs();
            this.updateAutoMapping();
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(this.expendedFields);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(reduceErrors(error));
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('entered handleSubmit - invalid inputs');
    }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<template>
<div class="wrap-all">
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header={modalHeader}>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Handover__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onerror={handleError}>
            <!-- Form Content -->
            <template if:false={lockThresholds}>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    </lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</div>
```

Parent JS:

```
@api recordId;
showHandover = false;
parentHeader = 'Close Process Mock - Parent Component';
result;



handleSubmitFromParent() {
    console.log('entered handleSubmitFromParent');
    this.template.querySelector('c-handover-from-opportunity').handleSubmit();
}

handleSuccess(event) {
    const handoverId = event.detail;
    this.result = 'Success from Child! Handover ID: ' + handoverId;
    this.showHandover = false;
}

handleError(event) {
    const error = event.detail;
    this.result = 'Error from Child! ' + error;
    this.showHandover = false;
}
```

}

Parent HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-quick-action-panel header={parentHeader}>
    <template if:false={showHandover}>
        <div slot="footer" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Start" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleStartHandover}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={showHandover}>
        <c-handover-from-opportunity context="Close Process" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess} onerror={handleError}></c-handover-from-opportunity>
        <div slot="footer" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit - From Parent" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleSubmitFromParent}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={result}>
        Completed! Result is: {result}
    </template>
</lightning-quick-action-panel>
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: It's just getting stuck on the part of: `const fields = this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').detail.fields;`

Answer (score 0):

The child component would need to forward the events to the parent component.

```
//child.js
handleSuccess(event) {
  const detail = {...event.detail};
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('success', { detail }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, my question is actually on the handleSubmit part... How to do the actuall submit from the parent- when the parent calls handle submit it's not able to access the actual fields because they are not forwarded in the handleSubmit(event)...